# not able to assign text in text view when data parsed from json object

Tags: objective-c, ios

I ve got a textview .I have initailized with ivar. and is connected in my nib file.i m parsing a json feed and i m getting the data .but when assigned to textview.i m getting the textview empty..could u guys help me out.below is the code.

```
-(void)steve:(NSData *)die
  {
NSDictionary *items=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:die options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];
    boom=[items objectForKey:@"description"];

self.textview.text = boom;
NSLog(@"souoiuoiu:%@",self.textview.text);  

  }
```

Comment: NSLog(@"souoiuoiu:%@", boom);  write this and check whether you are getting the string or not

Comment: Are you use `self.textview` is different from `nil`?

Comment: @sri:i m getting the string.the problem is if i m to assign in textview i m not getting the data in textview

Comment: I think your textview object is null value

Comment: could you tell  me where you have assigned the textview i mean in code or in xib

Comment: i ve assigned the textview in nib file and made connection using Iboutlet.

Answer (score 0):

What is boom here..? try this one..

```
self.textview.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[items objectForKey:@"description"]];
```

Comment: have u printed this string [items objectForKey:@"description"]..? wether u got the text? if yes check the textcolor & background color of textview may be it's same..